Man gets arm/leg cut in abandoned train tunnel, wound is burnt to stop bleeding
I have seen this movie in the early 80s on TV. I was a kid and don't really remember details except for the scene location and two shocking plot elements.

A few men are in an underground urban location: there are rails, so it's probably a metro or train tunnel, and it's looking old (or abandoned).
The group of men are fleeing something (cops?), one (or some) of the characters is likely to be the prisoner of the others.
I remember two shocking scenes for the young mind I was: 

One character gets his arm or leg cut, and another character burns the wound with a red-hot rail (or equivalent) to stop the bleeding.
One bad guy threatens a prisoner to rape him or his brother, then a grown man cries in shock (maybe the threatened person).

I've thought for years that this was a Donald Pleasence movie but a look at his filmography on IMDb wasn't conclusive.
It could also be starring actors like Kirk Douglas or Ernest Borgnine -- I think this movie has this kind of actors.
Note that I have recently watched The Taking of Pelham 123 as John's suggested but it's not the movie I'm looking for: there's no rape threat and nobody loses a limb.

It looks like The Taking of Pelham One Two Three, 1974. IMDb extract:

Four seemingly-unrelated men board subway train Pelham 1:23 at successive stations. Mr. Blue, Mr. Green, Mr. Grey and Mr. Brown are heavily armed and overpower the motorman and novice conductor to take control of the train. Between stations they separate the front car from the remainder of the train, setting passengers in the back cars and the motorman free. The four demand $1 million ransom within exactly one hour for the remaining eighteen hostages, including the conductor. If their demands are not met in time or their directions are not followed precisely, they will begin to shoot hostages dead, one every minute the money is late. Wisecracking Lt. Zach Garber of the transit police ends up being the primary communicator between the hijackers and the authorities, which includes transit operations, his own police force, the NYPD, and the unpopular and currently flu ridden mayor who will make the ultimate decision of whether to pay the ransom. 

This is not a 100% fit, but it seems close enough to see if you can verify it.
Here is the trailer:




Did someone actually lose a limb there and cauterize the wound? (I don't remember anything like that, but it has been a while)

@Walt I don't think so either. But there was a scene where a crook "cauterized" himself to death. Hence my comments in my post. I only posted in the first place because the asker indicated it might be the answer. More than once, I have found that the details/memories are sometimes not perfect.

@John I just watched Pelham and that's not the one I'm looking for. Good movie, though. :) And I see why you would think of this one, some visual cues are there - but that's not it. No limb cut and no rape threat. Thank you for your suggestion anyway, it was a nice shot.
